# Помогите получить ответ от сервера QIWI API C#

Tags: c#

```
// СОЗДАНИЕ ФОРМЫ
        var client = BillPaymentsClientFactory.Create(
            secretKey: "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiUDJQIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJwYXlpbl9tZXJjaGFudF9zaXRlX3VpZCI6IjU5Z29icC0wMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI3OTI3NDI1NTQ1MCIsInNlY3JldCI6ImZiZmM1YmQ4NDViYTU0YTlhNmZmYmNlMzQ4OTQ3Mzc3OTk0ZThiN2FhNDg5YjZjYTk0ODU1NjRkNz**********");

        var billid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var paymentUrl = client.CreatePaymentForm(
            paymentInfo: new PaymentInfo
            {
                PublicKey = "48e7qUxn9T7RyYE1MVZswX1FRSbE6iyCj2gCRwwF3Dnh5XrasNTx3BGPiMsyXQFNKQhvukniQG8RTVhYm3iP5iruAUULBX8EKZ3M57hheY214uMDEXk8Vi2tikH3XDHbi9PJBd5M4eojL1Myj2YotX25Poh4S8cZzuVz9H1135Bys*************",
                Amount = new MoneyAmount
                {
                    ValueDecimal = 1.1m,
                    CurrencyEnum = CurrencyEnum.Rub
                },
                BillId = billid/*Guid.NewGuid().ToString()*/,
                //SuccessUrl = "https://merchant.com/payment/success?billId=893794793973"
            }
            );

        var response = client.GetBillInfo(billid);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Подключенные библиотеки через NuGet:
`using Qiwi.BillPayments.Client;
using Qiwi.BillPayments.Model.In;
using Qiwi.BillPayments.Model;`

Я создал форму, через которую пользователь должен пройти и оплатить, я хочу получить состояние оплаты через эту самую форму, сама форма создается нормально, получаю на нее ссылку, но не понимаю как надо проверить состояние оплаты.
Qiwi получает состояние транзакции таким образом:
https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/bill-payments/?csharp#invoice-status
через .NET SDK.
Помогите получить вот такой ответ от сервера QIWI:
Код не хочет вставляться:
Вот тут https://github.com/QIWI-API/bill-payments-dotnet-sdk
Пролистайте до Информация о счете.
Сервер возвращает мне вот это:
Qiwi.BillPayments.Model.Out.BillResponse
Не то что нужно.
Буду искренне благодарен, уже очень долго парюсь

Решение:

```
// СОЗДАНИЕ ФОРМЫ
        BillPaymentsClient client = BillPaymentsClientFactory.Create(
            secretKey: "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiUDJQIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJwYXlpbl9tZXJjaGFudF9zaXRlX3VpZCI6IjU5Z29icC0wMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI3OTI3NDI1NTQ1MCIsInNlY3JldCI6ImZiZmM1YmQ4NDViYTU0YTlhNmZmYmNlMzQ4OTQ3Mzc3OTk0ZThiN2FhNDg5YjZjYTk0ODU1N**************"
            );

        BillResponse form = client.CreateBill(
           info: new CreateBillInfo
           {
               BillId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
               Amount = new MoneyAmount
               {
                   ValueDecimal = 199.9m,
                   CurrencyEnum = CurrencyEnum.Rub
               },
               Comment = "comment",
               ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(45),
               Customer = new Customer
               {
                   Email = "danil*************@bk.ru",
                   Account = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                   Phone = "892742*****"
               },
           }
           );

        BillResponse responseStatus = client.GetBillInfo(billId: form.BillId);
        string status =  responseStatus.Status.ValueString;
        Customer customer = form.Customer;
        Console.WriteLine(status);
```

Comment: `Сервер возвращает мне вот это: Qiwi.BillPayments.Model.Out.BillResponse` А вы уверены, что вам возвращает такое сервер, а не вы пытаетесь вывести класс в виде строи? Ибо это очень похоже на namespace и название класса.

Comment: Вы правы, но вопрос все равно остается как получить ответ от сервера)

Comment: Ну так наверно в классе `BillResponse` есть нужные вам данные?

Comment: Для начала поменяйте все `var` на нормальные названия классов(в VS это лампочка на поле, затем "Use explicit type")(забудьте вообще про `var`, у нас язык со строгой типизацией), чтобы не путаться и не пытаться выводить класс `BillResponse` как текст в консоль.

Comment: Изменил var на нужные классы, только теперь при запуске с периодичностью 1 к 3 запускам вылетает Исключение

Comment: Я не когда не пользовался var, пример использования API и там использовали var, я учту ваше замечание

Comment: Боже Евгений спасибо вам, я бы не когда не додумался что нужно рыскать в классе BillResponse. Получил состояние счета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// СОЗДАНИЕ ФОРМЫ
    BillPaymentsClient client = BillPaymentsClientFactory.Create(
        secretKey: "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiUDJQIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJwYXlpbl9tZXJjaGFudF9zaXRlX3VpZCI6IjU5Z29icC0wMCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI3OTI3NDI1NTQ1MCIsInNlY3JldCI6ImZiZmM1YmQ4NDViYTU0YTlhNmZmYmNlMzQ4OTQ3Mzc3OTk0ZThiN2FhNDg5YjZjYTk0ODU1N**************"
        );

    BillResponse form = client.CreateBill(
       info: new CreateBillInfo
       {
           BillId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
           Amount = new MoneyAmount
           {
               ValueDecimal = 199.9m,
               CurrencyEnum = CurrencyEnum.Rub
           },
           Comment = "comment",
           ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(45),
           Customer = new Customer
           {
               Email = "danil*************@bk.ru",
               Account = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
               Phone = "892742*****"
           },
       }
       );

    BillResponse responseStatus = client.GetBillInfo(billId: form.BillId);
    string status =  responseStatus.Status.ValueString;
    Customer customer = form.Customer;
    Console.WriteLine(status);
```